# Is it permissible to recite surah al kahf during menses

Tags: salat, women, jumuah, surat-al-kahf

Please help me clear this issue as ive search it on the web but i wasn't able to get a clear answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a big diffrence on this topic.

Some theoligens says that it is not allowed but doing duaa is okey and some says it is allowed because there is no direct porhibtation on it and when the women had there cycels the prophet (pbuh) didnt stop women from reading the quran but u cant read from the quran (book) if you use your phone so there is inshallah no problems for you sister

Hope that answers your question and reall sorry for the bad english